# NodeJS Puppeteer - How to automate login to dynamic website

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I want to login to this website https://m.dana.id/d/ipg/inputphone?phoneNumber=81291383895&ipgForwardUrl=elefen&isFromItemDigital=true using **NodeJS** and **Puppeteer** using the following code :

```
const start = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0',
    })
    const response = await page.goto("https://m.dana.id/d/ipg/inputphone?phoneNumber=85280302285&ipgForwardUrl=elefen&isFromItemDigital=true", {waitUntil: 'load'})
    const cookies = await page.cookies()
    const headers = response.headers()

    var sessid = ""
    var ctoken = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        if(cookies[i]["name"] == "ALIPAYJSESSIONID"){
            sessid = cookies[i]["value"]
        }
        if(cookies[i]["name"] == "ctoken"){
            ctoken = cookies[i]["value"]
        }
    }
    console.log(sessid + " - " + ctoken)

    await page.waitForSelector(".btn-continue.btn.btn-primary")
    await page.click(".btn-continue.btn.btn-primary")
    
    await page.goto("https://m.dana.id/d/ipg/ipgLogin", {waitUntil: 'load'})

    await page.screenshot({path: "test.png"})
    await browser.close()

}

start()
```

**What I got**

- [a-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5wHS.png)
- [a-2] 403 Error Forbidden

**What I need**

- [a-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5wHS.png)
- [a-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXBF7.png)
- [a-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy4cP.png)

Comment: If it's 2FA, consider logging in by hand and saving the cookie in `userDataDir`.

Comment: @ggorlen I want to do automate login into that site